# <a> tag problems and code behind problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a problem, that i can't find the solution for.

#### Code

```
<a runat="server" href="#" onclick="login_box();">
    <asp:Label ID="LabelLogin" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</a>
```

#### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserId"] == null)
    {
        LabelLogin.Text = "Login";
    }
    else
    {
        LabelLogin.Text = "Logud";
    }
}
```

It's okay, but now the problem is.

That i now want this one too on the 'a' tag's onclick, but it already got an "onclick" that opens the login box, this one checks for logged in or not, and if you aren't logged in, then it should open the "onclick login_box();" and if not, then it should logout.

This is used when you click on the either "login" or "logout".

I need a solution, for how i execute "onclick login_box" in code behind. And what i should do for the clicks, is it possible that i should move "login_box" to "onclientclick" and then i can use the "onclick" ?

```
if (Session["UserId"] == null)
{
    //Opens the login box
}
else
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: so you want to call a js function in c#

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but first i need to know if i can use "onclientclick" on <a> tag, then i can use "onclick" for codebehind?

Comment: my answer below allows you to call js function from C# , so you can remove your a tag click if you want and control all from codebehind . @Zeuthenjr let me know how it goes, me heading to sleep.. all the best

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can call JavaScript function in C#

```
public string functionname()
{

      Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
      page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CallMyClick", "<script type='text/javascript'>login_box();</script>");

}
```

Accessing ASP.NET Session variable using Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function LoginLogOut()
    {

        var userId = '<%= Session["UserId"] %>';
        if(userId != undefined)
        {
    document.getElementById("giveIdToAnchroTag").onclick = function (){LoginFunction();};
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("giveIdToAnchroTag").onclick = function (){logOutFunction();};

    }

 }
    </script>
```

Comment: "functionname()" is the new <a> tag onclick then, right?

Comment: nop, above code to stay in your C# , C# to call the javascript login box. Since a tag already is in html you have to call login box as it is. above code is sample to call a Javascript function via c# , you can use above one to call logout js function. still confused ?

Comment: Oh, so you want to tell me, that i can do so a tag onclick is executing the login_box function and that in c#, so how will you do it?

Comment: I dont think i understand what you mean..
Put up an example, about what you mean..

Comment: I dont understand how you will call "public string functionname()"
I only know that if you make "onclick=loginbox" then you write "public bool loginbox" in code behind

Comment: @Zeuthenjr so based on session variable you can change onclick of the anchor tag, what you say now ?

Comment: onlything is you should give some id to a tag.

Comment: I have to call the "LoginFunction" and the "logOutFunction" somehow?